# Splash screen coming in inverted way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

When i created App the launch image was correct and now its almost a month but when i run the app in device and simulator the splash screen is just inverted!!!  i don't know why ???

> Please check the attached images,Images are correct but when they
>   appear inside device or simulator its inverted

I have tried to remove the images and add it gain ,its not working .

Then i have created a new asset catalogs and added corresponding images.But now in iPad 3 its coming correct but iPhone its still wrong
[image]

Comment: probably a bug in the simulator.. did you try it out on a actual device?

Comment: yes,in ipad its correct but iphone its wrong

Comment: Do you have some linker warnings?

Comment: @Roma-MT no i didnt get any linker warnings

Comment: Well the only thing i can suggest is to remove those images also from the `plist` file and just put them again and see what happens

Comment: Also iPad and iPhone uses distinct images , the dimensions are not the same , so please recheck and double check your iPhone image .
also note that iPhone itself has couple of distinct dimensions like if you are using retina display or not will change the dims of the picture required.

Comment: @Roma-MT i have done this its not working but still i will do it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your plist file and look for Supported interface orientations (iPhone)

you will see some thing like the below attached image.

[image]

Make sure the sequence of the orientation levels is as shown in the above screen shot.

It worked for me. give it a try.